# Typescript module handbook sample not executing

Tags: typescript

I am trying module sample for validation in VS 2015, but it compiles fine but give error while execution.

test.ts file from handbook sample is giving execution error for line
validators['ZIP code'] = new Validation.ZipCodeValidator();

"Validation" is undefined., which is the name of module.

in VS I am able to use intellisense for module name, but when executing it is giving error for module name.

Thanks

Comment: Is the js file included in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Validation" is undefined., which is the name of module.

A definitive code ordering issue. Either `reference` comments are out of order (if you are using `--out`) or you need to fix the `script` tags you are using to load the files.

Comment: Thanks. issue was missing script tags for generated js files in my html page. Probably I need to learn on package loader like require.js to manage loading generated js files from my ts files.